# Modifying p tag with php variable

Tags: php, html, variables, paragraph

It's pretty simple thing but I'm unable to find any specific piece of code to help me.
So here's the deal. I have a variable in php and an html tag p.

**PHP**

```
$Complete = 'The form has been completed successfully';
```

**HTML**

```
<p id='END'> </p>
```

What I want to do is I want to modify the p tag to display what is stored in the php variable because I'll have more styling opportunities with the HTML CSS but I don't know how to get get the contents of php the variable in html. Please help me out.

I'm looking for a php piece of code.

Comment: I want a php code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this do it?

```
<p id='END'><?php echo $Complete; ?></p>
```

Or you could write it as

```
<?php echo '<p id="END">' . $Complete . '</p>'; ?>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed